# Printing a list to a Tkinter Text widget

Tags: python, text, tkinter, widget

I have a list of strings, and I want to print those strings in a *Tkinter* text widget, but I can't insert each string in a new line.

I tried this but didn't work:

```
ls = [a, b, c, d]

for i in range(len(lst)):
    text.insert(1.0+i lines, ls[i])
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Append newline (`'\n'`) manually:

```
from Tkinter import *  # from tkinter import *

lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

root = Tk()
t = Text(root)
for x in lst:
    t.insert(END, x + '\n')
t.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

BTW, you don't need to use index to iterate a list. Just iterate the list. And don't use `list` as a variable name. It shadows builtin function/type `list`.

Comment: You can also use a single `insert` statement along with `'\n'.join(lst)`

Answer (score 2):

You can also create a frame and pack (or grid) labels to it:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
myFrame = Frame(root).place(x=50, y=100)
myList = ["a", "b", "c"]
for i in myList:
    Label(myFrame, text = "● "+i).pack() #you can use a bullet point emoji.
root.mainloop()
```

This allows you to manage list items separately if you keep a reference (which I didn't).